# ¿Por qué Heroku elimina las imágenes que subo en mi aplicación?

Tags: python, django, heroku

Estoy desarrollando una tienda en línea y para mostrar la imagen del producto, la subo utilizando ImageField en forms.py.

El problema es que sí puedo visualizar la imagen del producto, pero pasa uno o dos días y ya no puedo verla.

este es el código en forms.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   partnumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
   description = models.TextField()
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images', null=False, blank=False)
   slug = models.SlugField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

este es el código de settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIAFILES_DIRS =( 
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
)
```

como pueden ver estoy subiendo las imágenes de los productos a una carpeta llamada images la cual esta en la carpeta static

[image: Como pueden ver esto es lo que pasa despues de 1 o 2 dias]

[image: aqui es inmediatamente despues que subo la foto del producto]

Comment: ¿qué quiere decir "ya no puedo verla"? ¿no sigue en el servidor?

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. Así es, despues del tiempo mencionado, la imágen ya no se encuentra en el servidor.

Comment: ¿dónde se están guardando? ¿será que tienes un script que borra periódicamente?

Comment: las imágenes se guardan en static/images que es la ruta que le doy en el upload_to en forms.py. En cuanto al script ya he estado revisando, pero no veo nada fuera de lo común.

Comment: ¿no tienes algún cron que haga limpieza de algún tipo? `crontab -l` para verlos

Comment: la aplicación la tengo desplegada en heroku, y en los settings de mi aplicación no tengo ningún crontab programado. ¿Usted cree es el problema sea del lado del servidor o el problema es generado por mi código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estás usando Heroku y allí guardas los datos, en lugar de en un lugar más *estable*.

De la página [Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) de la sección de ayuda de Heroku:

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

Es decir:

> El filesystem de Heroku es efímero - esto quiere decir que cualquier cambio en el filesystem mientras el dyno está corriendo solamente durarán hasta que el dyno se apague o se reinicie. Cada dyno se inicia con una copia limpia del filesystem del último deploy. Esto es igual a cómo operan muchos otros contenedores, como por ejemplo Docker.

Luego recomienda usar algún lugar que persista mejor, tipo S3 de Amazon o similares.

(Referencia: [Heroku deleting my images in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785044/1983854))

Comment: muchas gracias, ya me estaba volviendo loco porque no tenia idea de como atacar el problema. Buen día.

Comment: @GuillermoGarza ya lo creo! Ahora tocará implementar algo que suba a S3 o similar. Mucho éxito en la tarea